# Problema na resolução javascript

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo não deveria ser executado automaticamente recebendo os valores dos id's e os atribuindo ao array ui?

```
var ui = ["input", "prompt", "heading"];
ui.forEach(function(id){
   ui[id] = document.getElementById(id);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com esse código o que acho que queres é armazenar os elementos que têm esses id's do array ui, mas terá de ser uma ligeira modificação pois ui não é objeto

```js
var ui = ['input', 'prompt', 'heading'];
var eles = {} // objeto que vai armazenar os elementos com os id's de ui
ui.forEach(function(id) {
  eles[id] = document.getElementById(id);
});
console.log(eles);
```

```html
<div id="input">Input</div>
<div id="prompt">Prompt</div>
<div id="heading">Heading</div>
```

Agora temos todos os elementos guardados na varável `eles`.

Isto permite-nos por exemplo delegar um evento a cada um deles:

```js
var ui = ['input', 'prompt', 'heading'];
var eles = {} // objeto que vai aramazenar os elementos com os id's de ui
ui.forEach(function(id) {
  eles[id] = document.getElementById(id);
});
for(var ele in eles) {
 eles[ele].addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert('clicaste no elemento com o id: ' +this.id);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="input">Input (clica aqui)</div>
<div id="prompt">Prompt (clica aqui)</div>
<div id="heading">Heading (clica aqui)</div>
```

Desta meneira escusas de escrever `document.getELementById(..);` para cada um deles, assim como escusas de escrever/delegar os eventos um a um para cada elemento.

Comment: Muito obrigado Miguel! Mas o intuito não é indexar dessa forma: array[ElementHtml]  ?

Comment: De nada @LucasTrino. Bom Ano, e bem-vindo

Comment: @LucasTrino acho que te está a escapar alguma coisa, eles neste caso é um objeto em que cada key é o nome do id, não é o elemento, associado a cada key com respetivo valor é que temos os elementos

Answer (score 2):

Quando tens

```
ui[id] = document.getElementById(id);
```

o que isso faz é atribuir ao `ui` propriedades com ponteiros para o elemento do DOM. Não o seu valor mas sim o próprio elemento.

Se queres ter os valores deverias juntar `.value` assim:

```
ui[id] = document.getElementById(id).value;
```

Exemplo:

```js
var ui = {};
['a', 'b'].forEach(function(id) {
  ui[id] = document.getElementById(id).value;
});

console.log(ui);
```

```html
<input id="a" value="letra A" />
<input id="b" value="letra B" />
```

Comment: Sim, me expressei de uma forma ruim. Mas ele nao vai indexar o array ui desta forma: ui[elemento htm q tem um dos ids do array ui]?

Comment: @LucasTrino se quiseres ter `ui[elemento]` não podes usar um objeto, tens de usar um `Map`, é isso que procuras?

Comment: Não, isso foi o q eu pensei q fosse. Mas na realidade, o q o codigo acima faz?

Comment: @LucasTrino O código na minha resposta guarda os valores de cada `input` num array para, por exemplo, enviar para o servidor e processar esses dados.